# Algebra of "Big O" notation for a product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

I come again with a question concerning big O notation. As I don't find anything online about the algebra of big O notation, I would ask you about this problem.

Let $x, y>0$, $x$ constant and $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering if the inequality
$$ x^a\cdot O((xy)^b) = O((x^{a+b} y^b)) \quad\text{ as } y\to 0$$
is correct. The big O notation for me is the one in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

This is my argument: as $f(xy) = O((xy)^b)$ means there exists $M>0$ such that $f(xy)\le M (xy)^b$ as $y\to 0$, thus $x^a f(xy)\le x^{a+b} y^b$, i.e. $f(xy) = O((x^{a+b} y^b))$.
I don't know if it is a valid argument or not.

Could you please tell me if the equality written above and my argument hold true? If not, which is the correct way to write $ x^a\cdot O((xy)^b)$ like big O of something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $f$ a multivariable function of both $x$ and $y$ or is $y$ simply a constant?

Comment: @Jam actually $x$ is the constant. I edit the question on that.

Comment: @user603537 Then it's straightforwardly true since constants can be factored out of the big O operator.

Comment: @Jam thank you for the comment. So, it is true that $x^a\cdot O((xy)^b) = O((x^{a+b} y^b))$ or $x^a\cdot O((xy)^b) = O((xy)^b)$?

Comment: Since $y$ is the only variable(?)... both are true. It is also $O(y^b)$.